# get data from resultset after the execution of sql query in netbeans

Tags: sql, netbeans-7

I have created a table register in SQL with field username. In the JFrame when a user enters username there is a JButton for checking the username availability. For this I have used the code below:

```
String sqlstmt = "select username from register where username='" +
                 jTextField1.getText() + "'";

try {
  st = con.prepareStatement(sqlstmt);
  stmt = con.createStatement();
  rs = st.executeQuery(sqlstmt);

  if (rs.next()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"found");
  } else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"not found");
  }
} catch(SQLException e) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"sql error");    
}
```

when executing this query, it is seen that data is empty. Or if I put `rs.getString("username")` inside the `if (rs.next)`, it shows the "sql error" message.

Comment: Congratulations, you found a unique username that is not taken by anyone else yet. What's the problem?

Comment: after executing this code I want to check whether rs is empty or not.here it is always empty.But the same query gets username when executing in sql if the username found.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing `Statement`s and `PreparedStatement`s here.
The best approach here would probably be to use a `PreparedStatement`, which would take care of any funky characters from your input, and offer protection against SQL injection:

```
// SQL statement to prepare.
// Note the lack of single quotes  (') in the parameter
String sqlstmt= "select username from register where username = ?";

// Prepare the statement
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sqlstmt);

// Bind the argument
st.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());

// Execute
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

// Rest of the code to handle results...
```

**Note:**
This example omits error handling (e.g., try-catch constructs) in favor of clarity.

Comment: sir after this how to check rs is null or not?I used if(rs.next()).but its not working

Comment: `rs` can't be `null`, at least not with any sensible JDBC driver. Can you edit the question with what you tried and explain how the code's behavior is different from your expectation?